# Where can I find the complete reference document for CouchDb Design Docs syntax?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

Please don't tell me to "googleit"!

I have been poring over [the Apache pages](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/index.html) and [the IBM pages](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/design_documents.html#design-documents) for days trying to find the **full** allowed syntax for a Design Doc.

From the above readings:

- [the 'map' property](https://couchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ddocs/views/intro.html#what-is-a-view) is always a Javascript function
- [the 'options' property](https://couchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/ddoc/views.html#view-options) may be one/both of `local_seq` or `include_design`.

When I use Fauxton to edit a Mango Query, however, I see that the reality is much broader.

I defined a query ...

```
{
   "selector": {
      "data.type": {
         "$eq": "invoice"
      },
      "data.idib": {
         "$gt": 0,
         "$lt": 99999
      }
   },
   "sort": [
      {
         "data.type": "desc"
      },
      {
         "data.idib": "desc"
      }
   ]
}
```

... with an accompanying index ...

```
{
   "index": {
      "fields": [
         "foo"
      ]
   },
   "name": "foo-json-index",
   "type": "json"
}
```

... and then looked at the design doc produced ...

```
{
  "_id": "_design/5b1cf1be5a6b7013019ba4afac2b712fc06ea82f",
  "_rev": "1-1e6c5b7bc622d9b3c9b5f14cb0fcb672",
  "language": "query",
  "views": {
    "invoice_code": {
      "map": {
        "fields": {
          "data.type": "desc",
          "data.idib": "desc"
        },
        "partial_filter_selector": {}
      },
      "reduce": "_count",
      "options": {
        "def": {
          "fields": [
            {
              "data.type": "desc"
            },
            {
              "data.idib": "desc"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both of the published syntax rules are broken!

- `map` is not a function
- `options` defines the fields of the index

Where can I find a full description of **all** the allowed properties of a Design Document?

Comment: Using Mango you have created an Index. An index and a view are two different things, though they typically achieve the same goal.

Comment: Mango index are stored as Design documents and are not really documented. I guess the index format is for internal purpose only and should not be edited manually.

Comment: @HypnicJerk Yes, I see that.  Part of what I was trying to do, was to generate a bunch of similar Mango queries through a template, defining as many of the available settings as possible.

Comment: @AlexisCôté.  I agree that it is unwise to use undocumented features, but there's always the chance that Googling only turns up the introductory docs, not the definitive reference materials.  Apache and IBM are usually quite disciplined with that stuff, so I am surprised not to find it.